# where is the interrupt condition in the example code

Tags: embedded, interrupt

An interupt is when we stop the main code to run a sub code.
In the example bellow our interrupt code is a function called USART1_TX_IRQHandler.

We have these two lines where NVIC_enable says that USART1_TX_IRQn  is our interrupt function.

```
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_TX_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_TX_IRQn);
```

but i cant see in the code ,the codition we check before we are calling USART1_TX_IRQHandler.
How in the code i can see the codition in which we could know that USART1_TX_IRQHandler is about to be called?
Thanks.

```
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"
#include "em_ldma.h"

#define TX_BUFFER_SIZE   10
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE   TX_BUFFER_SIZE

uint8_t TxBuffer[TX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09};
uint32_t TxBufferIndex = 0;

uint8_t RxBuffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
uint32_t RxBufferIndex = 0;

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief USART1 TX IRQ Handler
 *****************************************************************************/
void USART1_TX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  // Send and receive incoming data
  USART_Tx(USART1, TxBuffer[TxBufferIndex++]);

  // Stop sending once we've gone through the whole TxBuffer
  if (TxBufferIndex == TX_BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
    TxBufferIndex = 0;
  }
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief USART1 RX IRQ Handler
 *****************************************************************************/
void USART1_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
  // Send and receive incoming data
  RxBuffer[RxBufferIndex++] = USART_Rx(USART1);

  // Stop once we've filled up our buffer
  if (RxBufferIndex == RX_BUFFER_SIZE)
  {
    // Place breakpoint here and observe RxBuffer
    // RxBuffer should contain 0xA0, 0xA1, 0xA2, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0xA5, 0xA6, 0xA7, 0xA8, 0xA9
    RxBufferIndex = 0;
  }
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Initialize USART1
 *****************************************************************************/
void initUSART1 (void)
{
    CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
    CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART1, true);

    // Configure GPIO mode
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 8, gpioModePushPull, 0); // US1_CLK is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 9, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_CS is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 6, gpioModePushPull, 1); // US1_TX (MOSI) is push pull
    GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortC, 7, gpioModeInput, 1);    // US1_RX (MISO) is input

    // Start with default config, then modify as necessary
    USART_InitSync_TypeDef config = USART_INITSYNC_DEFAULT;
    config.master       = true;            // master mode
    config.baudrate     = 1000000;         // CLK freq is 1 MHz
    config.autoCsEnable = true;            // CS pin controlled by hardware, not firmware
    config.clockMode    = usartClockMode0; // clock idle low, sample on rising/first edge
    config.msbf         = true;            // send MSB first
    config.enable       = usartDisable;    // Make sure to keep USART disabled until it's all set up
    USART_InitSync(USART1, &config);

    // Set USART pin locations
    USART1->ROUTELOC0 = (USART_ROUTELOC0_CLKLOC_LOC11) | // US1_CLK       on location 11 = PC8 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 8
                        (USART_ROUTELOC0_CSLOC_LOC11)  | // US1_CS        on location 11 = PC9 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 10
                        (USART_ROUTELOC0_TXLOC_LOC11)  | // US1_TX (MOSI) on location 11 = PC6 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 4
                        (USART_ROUTELOC0_RXLOC_LOC11);   // US1_RX (MISO) on location 11 = PC7 per datasheet section 6.4 = EXP Header pin 6

    // Enable USART pins
    USART1->ROUTEPEN = USART_ROUTEPEN_CLKPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_CSPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_TXPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_RXPEN;

    // Enabling TX interrupts to transfer whenever
    // there is room in the transmit buffer
    USART_IntClear(USART1, USART_IF_TXBL);
    USART_IntEnable(USART1, USART_IEN_TXBL);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_TX_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_TX_IRQn);

    // Enabling RX interrupts to trigger whenever
    // a new packet arrives from the slave
    USART_IntClear(USART1, USART_IF_RXDATAV);
    USART_IntEnable(USART1, USART_IEN_RXDATAV);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_RX_IRQn);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_RX_IRQn);

    // Enable USART1
    USART_Enable(USART1, usartEnable);
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Main function
 *****************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
  // Initialize chip
  CHIP_Init();

  // Initialize USART1 as SPI master
  initUSART1();

  // After the USART is initialized transfers will automatically start based off of certain interrupt flag conditions
  // A new packet will be sent to the slave whenever the TX Buffer is empty after a previous successful transfer
  // and a packet will be sent from the slave back whenever it receives a packet from the master and will be handled
  // by the USART_RX_IRQHandler
  while(1);
}
```

Comment: The whole point of interrupts is that they are called by hardware, not by software. In case of UART, that means either when a byte is sent, a byte is received or when various errors happen. You _can't_ know when it will get called, so information sharing with ISR must be guarded against non-atomic access of shared variables. But start by reading up about what an interrupt is and take it from there.

Comment: Here is a [video introduction to interrupts](https://youtu.be/jP1JymlHUtc?list=PLPW8O6W-1chwyTzI3BHwBLbGQoPFxPAPM)

Comment: Hello When I tested the code i see an endless proccess of sending the same buffer,
I want to send the buffer only ONCE, if i delete the condition of setting the index to the start of the array.
How do i turn off the interrups when it reaches the end of the buffer?
Thanks.